# mod-solo-lfg azerothcore - error: no member named

Tags: world-of-warcraft, azerothcore

I am trying to install this module: https://github.com/azerothcore/mod-solo-lfg

I am running the server on a Debian 10 droplet.

I dropped the mod into the modules folder and did
`git apply lfg-solo.patch`

This is the error I'm getting:

```
/home/nori/azerothcore/modules/mod-solo-lfg-master/src/Lfg_Solo.cpp:44:27: error: no member named 'IsSoloLFG' in 'lfg::LFGMgr'
            if (!sLFGMgr->IsSoloLFG())
                 ~~~~~~~  ^

/home/nori/azerothcore/modules/mod-solo-lfg-master/src/Lfg_Solo.cpp:46:22: error: no member named 'ToggleSoloLFG' in 'lfg::LFGMgr'
            sLFGMgr->ToggleSoloLFG();
            ~~~~~~~  ^

2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/build.make:7792: src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/__/__/__/modules/mod                     -solo-lfg-master/src/Lfg_Solo.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1283: src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgKEM.png <- Image of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two members `IsSoloLFG` and `ToggleSoloLFG` arent found in the lfg::LFGMgr.

you could look in the server source to see if the patch added the updates, which it seems to have not.

you can try re-applying the patch, or you can add the changes manually.